# Get List of properties from a List of objects corresponding to another property

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of objects with properties Id, Title and Color. Each item with a particular Id is assigned with a title and color. I want two lists 1) List of all titles and List of all colors.

I get the titles from the list like

```
var dataSet = mList.Select (c => c.Title).Distinct.ToList();
```

Now I want the list of colors, corresponding to the titles in the dataSet.

If I do:

```
var colordataSet = mList.Select (c => c.Color).Distinct.ToList();
```

I get all the colors in the parent list irrespective of the title/id. I want the colors Assigned to the items with the titles in the list of titles.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a dictionary and transform the list with [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657(v=vs.110).aspx) of `System.Linq.ToDictionary`:

```
Dictionary<string,Color> dict = mList.ToDictionary(c => c.Title,  //Keyselector
                                                   c => c.Color); //Elementselector
```

Then you can get the corresponding color for a title:

```
Color color = dict["ColorForThisTitle"];
```

**Edit:** To have distinct `Title` in the dictionary:

```
var dict = mList.GroupBy(k => k.Title, (k,c) => c.FirstOrDefault())
                .ToDictionary(c => c.Title,
                              c => c.Color);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer . Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify what @Alexander did...you can use ToLookUp

```
var getColorsbyTitle = mList.ToLookUp(c=>c.Title,c=>c.Color);

//you can use this like below

var color  = getColorsByTitle("xyz").FirstorDefault();
```

Note: This internally does same thing Group by with ToDictionary.